# django could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host and accepting TCP/IP connections on port remote host

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a weird problem. I can connect to a remote host using psql from the command line but can't using the exact same credentials in a django settings file. I get the error:

> Could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running
>   on host "remote ip" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port
>   port_number?

If I can connect using psql and not using django what am I missing here? I also checked through python interpreter that I can load psycopg2.

Any help is greatly appreciated as non of what I've found online has helped.

Cheers,

D

Here's the db conf in settings.py

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': '<db name goes here>', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '<db user>', # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '<pswd goes here>', # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '<remote ip goes here>', 
        'PORT': '5432', 
}
```

Comment: You will need to post some example code/configuration.

Comment: I could do that...but here's something more interesting...I can run the command python manage.py runserver and I can use the site...it has to be something with apache but what does apache have to do with db connections?

Comment: Of course it does. Apache is running your application server (mod_wsgi) as a module. You might not have permission to connect to the database as the user running wsgi/apache if postgres is only allowing connections from a certain user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your description this has something to do with the Apache and it's permissions to access the database. You didn't mention which OS you use but if it is running SELinux the default rules prevent apache from connecting to db. If this is the case you can temporarily enable it by running:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db
```

[Here](http://mdious.fedorapeople.org/drafts/html/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Booleans-Configuring_Booleans.html) are more detailed instructions.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that...this is on Red Hat.

Comment: That did the trick...rebooted afterwards and everything was fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

To make changes persistent across reboots (tested on Centos):

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

read more [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Booleans-Configuring_Booleans.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on CentOs.

```
service httpd stop

service postgresql stop

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

service httpd start

service postgresql start
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving the wrong authentication credentials to the Django application can lead to this problem. In order to solve it, you can follow these steps:

1. Check that Postgres is installed:

   `apt show postgresql`
2. Check that PostgreSQL is running:

   `sudo service postgresql status`
3. Check that you can actually connect to PostgreSQL

   `sudo su - postgres`
4. Once in user *postgres* run the command interface

   `psql`
5. Check the connection info by running:

   `\conninfo`

In my case, I installed Postgres long ago and just forgot access information like username, password, name of database or port access.